# Custom GitHub PR comment triggers for Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to trigger somehow Azure Pipelines with custom GitHub Pull Request comments (besides the [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#comment-triggers) ones)?
We’ve found the following [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-triggers.md#webhook-triggers) suggesting to use webhook triggers but as far as I understand this feature isn’t yet implemented in Azure Pipelines, is it?

Comment: There was a question asked recently about marshaling additional arguments to use in a pipeline.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997619/possible-to-trigger-a-build-via-github-pr-comment-with-some-arguments If that does not help for what you are after, can you explain the why a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Custom GitHub PR comment triggers for Azure Pipelines

Yes, you are right. The feature `Incoming Webhook` should not yet implemented in Azure Pipelines at this time.

Now, Azure pipeline trigger only support the "standard" GitHub Pull Request comments, like `/AzurePipelines run`or `/AzurePipelines run <pipeline-name>`. So we could not use the custom GitHub PR comment trigger the Azure pipeline currently.

The workaround as Levi Lu answered in that post, but the limitation is that the pipeline still needs to be executed for each PR.

If above workaround not help you, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Submitted a feature request here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/905960/custom-pr-comment-triggers-for-azure-pipelines.html